# How to disable the process of JComponents

Tags: java, swing

```
savebtn.setEnabled(false);
```

Using the above code i disable my save button.But when i click that button the save process will work. How to stop that process when clicking disabled button.

Comment: Are you sure that your button has been disabled ? Has it been greyed in the interface ?

Comment: _How to stop that process when clicking disabled button_ Are you sure , you cant click a disabled button

Comment: You've attached a `MosueListener` to the button haven't you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable a `JButton` with `setEnabled(false)`, its registered [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)s will not be called when you click on the button.

However if you added a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to it with `addMouseListener()` method, even if the button is disabled, the registered `MouseListener` will still be called.

You should register an `ActionListener` to do the job that is required when the button is pressed/clicked. That way if you disable the button, the `ActionListener` will not be called if the button is clicked.

See the following example: if you click on the button, it will only print `"clicked"` but it will not print `"action performed"`.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JButton b = new JButton("Test");
b.setEnabled(false);
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("action performed");
    }
});
b.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }
});
f.add(b);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

If you remove the `b.setEnabled(false);` line and you click on the button output will be :

```
clicked
action performed
```

Comment: +1.  Also look into using an `Action`.  Disabling an *action* will disable any controls (e.g. both a button and menu item) using that action.